# How to verify amazon in-app purchase receipt verification against sandbox outside of the app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I read the link [amazon in-app purchase receipt verification against sandbox outside of the app](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/documentation/testing-iap.html)

But am not able to figure out what url should i set for test the receipt verification against sandbox server. They mentioned that for production use **https://appstore-sdk.amazon.com/version/2.0/verify....**. Any one knows about this then please share it.

Also why they mentioned "JEE Web Container" for configuration. In that case for Apache what they will do?.

-loganathan

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out of my own. I used jetty webservice to achieve that. Here the link. [jetty free webservice host](http://jelastic.com/jetty-hosting)